# AngularJS - Retrieve param values from the route (URL)

Tags: angularjs

I have the following URL:
`http://mysite:9000/#/sso/salesforce/666`

I added my route the following way:

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/sso/salesforce/:companyId', { ....
```

I'm trying to resolve the companyId from the URL, in this case `666`:
http://mysite:9000/#/sso/salesforce/666

I'm injecting $location into a resolve function to resolve the company ID, but I'm not sure how to get it from $location.

`$location.search()` gives me an object with a property 'companyId: true' 
I don't need to know that is present, I need to get the actually value `666`.

How is this done in angular 1? I'm new to angular, not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject and use `$routeParams` for this as below.

In the config,

```
$routeProvider.when('/sso/salesforce/:companyId', {
            templateUrl: '/sso/salesforce/' + $routeParams.companyId + '.html'
        });
```

In the controller,

```
function RouteController($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.templateUrl = '/sso/salesforce/' + $routeParams.companyId + '.html';
    }
```